# How to use boost::ref with Boost.Parameter library when passing arguments?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-parameter, boost-ref

I use the Boost.Parameter library for providing named parameters to a constructor.

```cpp
BOOST_PARAMETER_NAME(windowFunction)

namespace detail
{

struct ClassAImpl
{
    template <class ArgumentPack>
    ClassAImpl(ArgumentPack const& args)
        : mWindowFun(args[_windowFunction])
            , [...]
    {

    }

    boost::function<bool(int, int)> mWindowFun;
    [...]
};
}

struct ClassA : detail::ClassAImpl
{
    BOOST_PARAMETER_CONSTRUCTOR(
            ClassA, (detail::ClassAImpl), tag
          , (optional (windowFunction,*)
            [...]))
};
```

Usually `windowFunction` will be copied by the `boost::function` object, however I want to also be able to pass by reference with `boost::ref`.

However when I pass a function object with `boost::ref` the `reference_wrapper<T>` is removed and the ArgumentPack contains a reference to the `T` value.

**Question:** Is there a way to prevent the removal of the `reference_wrapper<T>` wrapper?

Example:

```cpp
SomeFunctionObject s;
ClassA a(windowFunction = boost::ref(s));
```

will have `SomeFunctionObject& s` passed to `mWindowFun` in the constructor of `ClassAImpl` instead of `const reference_wrapper<SomeFunctionObject>&`. Thus, `s` will be copied by `boost::function` which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

This seems currently not possible as Boost Parameter is explicitly unwrapping `reference_wrapper`s.

This is necessary for allowing to pass positional arguments by reference.